Academic careerism: How can there be biased research or dishonest inquiry in theoretical hard sciences?
From Wikipedia: (emphasis added)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_careerism

Academic careerism is the tendency of academics (professors specifically and intellectuals generally) to pursue their own enrichment and self-advancement at the expense of honest inquiry, unbiased research and dissemination of truth to their students and society. Such careerism has been criticized by thinkers from Socrates in ancient Athens to Russell Jacoby in the present.

Question: Since this article doesn't make any distinction between hard vs soft sciences, what does 'advancement at the expense of honest inquiry, unbiased research and dissemination of truth' look like in extremely theoretical hard sciences like theoretical/pure maths, pure physics or pure computer science, etc?
As far as I know, theoretical hard sciences don't have 'bias' the way soft/social sciences do. I can't imagine someone will focus on algebraic topology over complex geometry for some Israel vs Palestine political agenda or something. Maybe in some of the applied hard sciences even like applied physics or engineering ok maybe there can be some agenda, but theoretical?
cf1
How do you know that their answers are correct?
cf2
Ben Shapiro - 2024May03 - Time To DEFUND The Universities (emphasis added)

parents it's time to stop sending our kids to these universities it really really is unless they're in the physics department or the math department or the hard Sciences you should not be sending your kids to these universities you should find them an internship somewhere get them a job get them an apprenticeship give them the money to go into business


Someone gave Deutsche Physik as an example. Is this pure physics? How about in pure maths - is it possible to destroy the world / be evil?


I think that this is, in principle, a legitimate question (and I upvoted). I think the question would benefit, though, from tidying it up a bit - for instance by removing the two links at the end which do not seem to add much to the question (in particular the Shapiro quote seems mainly like a trigger for political debate) and by phrasing the post a bit more seriously (e.g., by avoiding "Lol").

@JochenGlueck  It IS weird Wikipedia doesn't say issues of bias don't really exist in theoretical hard sciences right? I mean unless they DO...

Sorry, I don't understand your response to my comment. In particular, I did not refer to the link to Wikipedia in my comment.

You are setting up a false dichotomy by setting self-advancement against honest inquiry.

There was indeed a Deutsche Mathematik counterpart to Deutsche Physik and people like Bieberbach expressed very biased views about mathematical results such as the Cauchy integral theorem; see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Bieberbach#Politics and https://www.tabletmag.com/sections/arts-letters/articles/hitlers-math

There's no need to show an edit history in the actual question body ("Edit 1", "Edit", etc.) If someone wants to review, they can go to the edit link. Clean this up so that you just show your question in its intended state. And why are you "lol"-ing at your own content?

I'm going to attempt to answer this question as if it is asked in good faith, although quoting people like Ben Shapiro suggests a definite agenda here.
Here are a few ways that academic careerism can impact hard sciences:

When refereeing papers, asking that people cite specific papers one or one's friends or colleagues are authors of.
When serving on grant committees, giving grants to research programs that build on one's own ideas or thematically connected ideas rather than the best grants.
When refereeing papers insisting that they give more credence to hypotheses one supports and downplay the likelihood of hypotheses one personally finds unlikely.

All of these can happen in even the most pure fields.

1- My agenda is Wikipedia doesn't say issues of bias don't really exist in theoretical hard sciences. I mean ... unless they do? 2- So please give examples of what you're citing. 3- I mean, what political agenda is a pure mathematician advancing if they cite a paper from Al Jazeera that explains a variation of cauchy's differentiation formula? 4- if i were al jazeera, then why would i waste time or money on a pure mathematician? 5- when does anyone look at a PURE MATHS paper and say 'oh cites al jazeera not credible' ?

@BCLC Please reread the examples I gave. They all address issues of careerism. You are taking the notion of careerism and insisting that it only come with a certain, specific political gloss. The quote you gave at the start does not make that assumption at all.

@BCLC If you do want to ask about politically specific issues, then please say so. There are certainly a lot of examples. You ask about "algebraic topology over complex geometry for some Israel vs Palestine political agenda or something. Lol." But even there there are examples. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Physik as a classic case.

JoshuaZ 6 - ok thanks good example so why not include that in your answer? 7 - wait is that really pure physics? there's a part there 'Effect on the German nuclear program' 8 - any in pure maths? because if none then well......... https://i.sstatic.net/9QhlEjcK.png

9 - explain please how 'When refereeing papers insisting that they give more credence to hypotheses one supports and downplay the likelihood of hypotheses one personally finds unlikely.' can happen in PURE MATHS.

10 - 'When refereeing papers, asking that people cite specific papers one or one's friends or colleagues are authors of.' - i don't understand this in pure maths. how do i cite an alternative paper - like 2 people have the same proof for a thing? so what if i do? how is that corrupt? it's the same output ultimately you're just favouring your friends.

11 - 'When serving on grant committees, giving grants to research programs that build on one's own ideas or thematically connected ideas rather than the best grants.' - please give a pure maths example please. only thing i can think: if no one in our department is researching eg 'probabilistic group theory', then how's the best grant going to be this niche thing? i understand this in soft sciences because if you want to advance a political agenda, then there's bias towards 'agreement'. i don't imagine bias if you think riemann hypothesis is true and then someone else thinks it's false.

@BCLC: Please note that it will not help you to get further useful answers (or to get your question re-opened in the first place) if you reply to an answer by an argumentative list of demands.

@BCLC " explain please how 'When refereeing papers insisting that they give more credence to hypotheses one supports and downplay the likelihood of hypotheses one personally finds unlikely.' can happen in PURE MATHS"
Sure.  I'm in pure math. In my niche there is a specific conjecture that people are deeply uncertain about. I've gone back and forth about whether I believe it, but a few other people have strong, pretty set opinions about it.  Phrasing about how likely it is to be true in a paper would be an obvious impact there.

@BCLC: Regarding requests for clarification: 10) You seem to assume that people only cite papers whose results they use, but this is not the case. In most papers a considerable number of citations are simply there to provide sufficient context. There's a lot of choice regarding which papers one cites for context - and referees can  exert a lot of influence here if they want to.

@BCLC Regarding "When refereeing papers, asking that people cite specific papers one or one's friends or colleagues are authors of.' - i don't understand this in pure maths."
Let's take a specific example here: there are around 50-100 papers about different restrictions about what an odd perfect number must satisfy. Any introduction in a paper on the topic is unlikely to be able to cite all of them. So a referee could insist one add a specific additional paper. And for other topics (like say RH) there are literally 1000s of papers so the same situation but even more so.

@BCLC Sure; let's pick another example: geometric complexity theory. There are some people who think it is an extremely promising approach to understanding computational  complexity, and others consider it to be a complete pie in the sky. So someone could let their own biases there influence grants. Or they could even think two approaches to something are both equally promising, but support grants for studying the one their friends do more of.

@BCLC: Regarding 11): One of my research topics is order structures in functional analysis. Now say a grant agency sends me a grant proposal to review where somebody wants to analyse a certain aspect of, say, PDE theory by using order structures in functional analysis and the proposal cites some of my papers. Let's assume that the proposal does not appear to be thought through very well: if the proposal gets funded, I believe the PI will produce two or three insignificant and somewhat obscure papers without interesting new insights. [...]

[...] So I should recommend to reject to proposal. But if I were a careerist who cared more about his career than about advancing mathematics I could still recommend to fund the proposal - as I know that the papers that come out of the grant will probably cite some of my papers.

One problem is, of course, that it's not at all clear where the line is between supporting a line of research because one genuinely believes that it leads to mathematical adcances and supporting a line of research mainly because it's helpful to one's own career. It's very blurry and one can almost always claim (to others and also to oneself) that one was doing the first thing when one was actually doing the second.
